# Can someone tell me the regex for a dateTimeString like: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS"

Tags: java, regex, datetime, format, timestamp

Also, I'd really appreciate an explanation. Sorry, but I have never used regexes in my life and can barely read them.

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` for this task. Anyways, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you need a regex rather than just parsing it using `SimpleDateFormat`? Can you give us more background?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on the web, for instance [this one](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm).  You could read this and learn how to construct your own regular expressions.

Comment: And plenty of sites to test your regexs like [this one](http://www.regexplanet.com/)

Comment: @JavaDevil note that a RegEx would be far too complicated to validate a date.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I was merely pointing out the availability of such places to test a regex not suggesting that a regex should be used to validate dates

Comment: For better understanding regex and its syntax, you may want to try [this website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Comment: Sorry, this was for an xml validation task wherein I had to validate a date string using a regex. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

- `\d` is a digit
- `{4}` is the amount of digits (the regexp part right in front of it)
- `/` is just a slash
- `:` is just a colon
- `\s` is any whitespace
- `+` is one or more of whitespace (the regexp part right in front of it)

Note that this may be used for a quick initial check, but you should use other methods of checking the full date format such as the `SimpleDateFormat` advertised by Rohit Jain or Jon Skeet.

Comment: Note that you can narrow hours and such down, but you are probably better off testing that using the numbers themselves.

Comment: -1: So I can enter something like `0000/99/99 99:99:99` and would be a *valid* date?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. Regular expressions are not really fit to check a full date format. You would get really ugly code to make sure that an hour is 0 to 24 (exclusive). That's not what regular expressions are for.

Comment: Then this is not what an answer should look for =\. Still, guide OP in the **right direction** and promote the usage of a `DateFormat`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza true, but then again, how would you implement invalid day light savings or even simple leap years? You will have to check the date itself programmatically anyway.

Comment: That's all covered in a `DateFormat` class like [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza added reminder to do full check later on. Note that sometimes you can only use regular expressions within a framework to initially check data.

Comment: Not totally agreed with your last statement, but since OP hasn't posted the purposes to use a RegEx, you *could* have a valid point. Still, a RegEx is not suited for this case, is like using RegEx to parse HTML.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree with what you are saying, but lets agree that there may be some use cases where it is useful to do some initial check with the regular expression. I would never ever check a date/time just by using a regular expression myself, if it could be avoided.

Comment: If you won't do it, then do not post it as advice =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza did you see the last comment of the author on the question?

Comment: Just now. Still, OP probably did it since it didn't know about DateFormat class.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out Date time is an irregular expression. It is impossible to validate
solely by regular expression. Leap seconds alone preclude that. The best you can do is to limit the false positives. However the more false positives you eliminate the more complex
the expression will be.

for the time component you can use this

`([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])`

- `[x]` means this matches x
- `[a-z]` means this matches any letter from a-z
- `a|b` means this matches a or b
- `(..)` groups the match

  so

`([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9])` will match  20-23 or 00-19 or 1-9

for the date part

`\d{4}/([1][0-2]|[0][0-9])/([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])`

as you can see it is getting very large and we still have a number of false positives.

put it together

`\d{4}/([1][0-2]|[0][0-9])/([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9]) ([2][0-3]|[0-1][0-9]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]:([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])`

This will allow `0000\02\31 01:59:60` which is not valid on so many levels.

It will also not allow `999\02\12 01:59:59` ,that can be remedied by replacing
`\d{4}` with `\d+`.

`+` means 1 or more.

my regex foo is fairly lacking so I always go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for help

p.s. While date time is normally 60 seconds 60 minutes 24 hours 365 days the lunar/solar calendars are not stable. Some calendars ignore this, UTC does not,
The most recognisable artefact in the western calendar is to add a leap day at the end of February roughly every 4 years. The next most common artefact is to add a leap second at irregular periods. This can be both positive and negative so the length of a minute can range from 59-61 seconds.

Comment: This is good but it allows "60" for seconds. It should be "59" like the minutes right?

Comment: I think changing the last [6][0] to [5][0] corrects this.

Comment: 60 seconds is intentional lookup leap seconds in your favourite search engine

Comment: @user2568374 if you want to ignore leap seconds replace `([0-5][0-9]|[6][0])` with `[0-5][0-9]`